# Laravel Event Handlers & Listeners

Tags: events, laravel, laravel-4, listeners, handlers

I have a question about Laravel's Event Handlers and Listeners. I have no idea where to start.

I would like to know what exactly are Events and when to use them. Also I would like to know what the best way to organize events and listeners is, and where to place them (in which folder).

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've recently implemented a feed for actions, e.g. when a post is created, a new user is registered, or whatever. Every action fires an event and for every event there's a listener, which saves something like "User XY just registered!" in the database.

Very basic version:

```
// app/controllers/RegistrationController.php
class RegistrationController {
    public function register($name) {
        User::create([
            'name' => $name
        });

        Event::fire('user.registered', [$name]);
    }
}

// app/events.php
Event::listen('user.registered', function($name) {
    DB::table('feed')->insert(
        [
            'action' => 'User ' . $name . ' just registered!'
            // ...
        }
    );
});
```

To use the events.php file, add the following line to your `app/start/global.php`

```
require app_path().'/events.php';
```

Now you can put all events in the events.php.

---

*But* if you're going to have a lot of events, you shouldn't put all of your events in a single file. See [Event Subscribers](http://laravel.com/docs/events#event-subscribers).

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed :) This makes it way easier to test my controllers.

Comment: Hi @Melvin Koopmans, I want to fire an event when a user logs in. I am using laravel 5 built in auth. Where should I fire the event?

Comment: You can fire the event in the controller. When you hit the specific controller method, then you can define your event fire. Then, laravel automatically fire your event for you.